# Value attribute is expected when creating aws internet gateway with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create an internet gateway with terraform. Following the [terraform documentation][1] I have the following block

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "prod-igw" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id}"
    tags = {{
        Name = "pos-igw"
    }
}
```

After applying I get this error message.

```
Error: Missing attribute value
Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=").
```

There's nothing about value in the documentation though.
[1]: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "prod-igw" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
    tags = { # <--- there was an extra {
        Name = "pos-igw"
    }
}
```

Please make sure to use a modern IDE (e.g., VScode) where there is a terraform extension which will prevent these things from happening and you will not have to ask a question on SO.